# Create View from a controller in asp.net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am trying to create new view using `Asp.Net MVC`. My view created successfully along with respective changes in my controller but

> it shows 404 error as the view is not included in project.

After including if I am trying to run this and hit `url/controller/Action` its working perfectly.

My code is as follows for creating view and adding action in controller

// My main aim is to create new page dynamically

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(Content model)
{
    var fileName = model.Name; // validate to check the same name don't exist.
    if (!System.IO.File.Exists(fileName))
    {
        System.IO.File.Create(Server.MapPath("~/Views/Custom/"+fileName+".cshtml"));
    }
    //start Append data in custom controller
    var lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(Server.MapPath("~/Controllers/CustomController.cs"));
    System.IO.File.WriteAllLines((Server.MapPath("~/Controllers/CustomController.cs")), lines.Take(lines.Length - 2).ToArray());
    //start Append data in custom controller
    //System.IO.File.WriteAllLines((Server.MapPath("~/Controllers/CustomController.cs")), "public ActionResult'" + fileName + "'(){");
    string appendData = "public ActionResult "+ fileName+ "() \n { \n";
    appendData += "return View();";
    appendData += " \n } \n } \n }";
    System.IO.File.AppendAllText((Server.MapPath("~/Controllers/CustomController.cs")), appendData);
    objcontext.objContent.Add(model);
    objcontext.SaveChanges();
    ModelState.Clear();
    return View();
}
```

Please help me how to include the file dynamically where I don't need to do manual include.

Comment: Why would you want to do this? what a mess

Comment: I want to give admin a privilege to create new page from back-end.

Comment: You can use dynamic actions and routing rather than trying to create actions in a controller, something like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25765196/implementing-routes-for-dynamic-actions-in-mvc-4-0

Comment: Yeah. Wow. This is just tremendously *bad*.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve dynamic controller by loading Assembly during execution. But writing a cs class, it won't work.

Have a look at below approach
http://www.strathweb.com/2012/06/using-controllers-from-an-external-assembly-in-asp-net-web-api/

Comment: You got me wrong. I want to create new view. For this I need to create a file and action in a controller which is working perfectly in by provided code. As the view is not included in my application it shows 404. After including if I run then it works.